# Invoke function without parentheses?

Tags: javascript

I know `forEach` takes a function as a parameter. But why do I have to call it like this `forEach(myFunction)` and not like this `forEach(myFunction())`?

What, fundamentally, is the difference?

Comment: `forEach` takes a function as an argument ... `myFunction` is a function ... `myFunction()` is the result of calling a function

Comment: Well, I see that it takes function as an argument. But what is the point to call it without "()"? @Bravo

Comment: `myFunction` is a function ... `myFunction()` calls the function and returns a value which would then be used as the argument ... unless `myFunction()` returns a function, then you are not passing a function as an argument - each iteration of `forEach` CALLS the supplied function with several arguments ... `myFunction(item, index, wholeArray)`

Comment: You are not calling it. You are *giving it* to `.forEach()`, so that `.forEach()` can call it.

Comment: @Bravo, thank you for your effort to explain. But something that I do not understand, and I do not know what is that exactly :) 
Would you mind to show it with code examples, and similar "problems"?
For ex, what if I would like to add arguments to myFunction() while using forEach?

Comment: forEach calls myFunction with the arguments as stated ... the first is the current item in the array, the second is the index and the third is the whole array .. you can name the arguments anything you like, but they will always be those values ... [see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for how to use forEach - read [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Printing_the_contents_of_an_array) specifically

Comment: @UlviEnzo Think of the simple `const f = myFunction; f();`. Now `f` is not a variable but a function parameter, but still the same concept. You pass around the function object without making a call.

Answer (score 1):

forEach takes a function as a parameter. When you pass a function as a parameter, you can pass its reference. `myFunction` is a reference to your function, while `myFunction()` is a calling of it. So imagine having this code:

```
const ar = [1, 2, 3]

const loopFunction = (item) => {
  console.log(item)
}
```

Now you can call forEach like so:

```
ar.forEach(loopFunction)
```

See how you used a reference to `loopFunction` to pass it into forEach? You can safely rewrite the above code like this:

```
const ar = [1, 2, 3]

ar.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item)
})
```

And thus altogether skip creating that function outside forEach.

Hope this helps a little.